# Using regexps to strip off base64 images from a .vcf file using Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I have an Apple Address Book exported as .vcf where the contacts images are stored as base64.
I'm trying to use Emacs to strip the photos out of the file.

An image in the file looks like this (the ^M are added by the exporter):

```
...
PHOTO;BASE64:^M
  /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAFEAAQABAAD/4imoSUNDX1BST0ZJTE95AQEAACmYYXBwbAIAAABtbnRyUkdC
  IFhZWiAH2QAIAB0AZFARAARRY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAA
  ...
  G8VVxuGjKs7uxniIKnO0SCOAeXn+InJo8sacff7woor3jEfujQH5e9FFAAH/2===^M
...
```

And I'm trying to query-replace on the following (I use Ctrl-q to insert the ^M and ^J):

```
PHOTO;BASE64:^M^J*^M^J
```

But that doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: What you are essentially missing is that `^J*` means zero or more literal line feeds. In regex, the asterisk is a postfix repetition operator, not a "match anything" wildcard (like in glob patterns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
PHOTO;BASE64:^M[^^M]*?^M^J
```

`^^M` contains two characters `^` and `^M`. It matches everything except `^M`

Comment: This is wrong. With `[^^M]` are you creating a character class that matches everything but `^` and `M`. (and not NOT the sequence ^M)

Comment: If you are testing with the example from the OP, then the only reason it is working is, that there is no `M` and no `^` in his test sequence except the markers at the start and the end. For the `^` its possible that its never there, but I am quite sure that there are `M`s in reality.

Comment: Ok, I checked it also with a sequence with ^ and M characters. It works. Again, in my example ^M is one character

Comment: @sterna: the read what Oleg already wrote. `^M` is a literal carriage return; you'd type ctrl-Q ctrl-M, not caret shift-M.

Comment: Oleg, you're absolutely right. It works fine. When I've tried it the first time, I used by mistake the shortcut for replace string, instead of replace regexp. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the `^J` are good for. Is this something emacs special? I also don't know if emacs has a dotall modifier, but you can try this (to my regex experience with other engines)

```
PHOTO;BASE64:^M(\s|[^\s])*?^M
```

Emacs regex is explained here: [www.emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)

`\s` is a whitespace character

`[^\s]` is anything but whitespace

So the regex mean match anything between ^M and ^M